# Given that $\gcd(a,b) =1$, show that $\gcd(a+2b,b)=1$ without using prime factorization theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd(a,b) =1$, show $\gcd(a+2b,b)=1$. I need help figuring how to showing from just that $\gcd(a,b) =1$. Does it have to do with Euclidean formula and that $\gcd(a,b) = am + bn$ for some $m,n$? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly you are asking the same question twice http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491923/if-gcda-b-1-show-gcda2b-b-1  ??
 A good and thorough answer is there !!

Answer (score 2):

If $d|a+2b$ and $d|b$ then $d|a+2b-2(b)=a$ so $\gcd(a+2b,b)|a$ and $\gcd(a+2b,b)|b$. So that gcd divides $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: a-2b? do you mean a+2b

Comment: Your welcome. What do you mean gcd divides gcd(a,b)?

Comment: All divisors of a+2b and b divide both a and b, in particular so does the gcd of the former two.

Comment: Sorry  @AdamHughes  but why $d|a+2b-2(b)$?

Comment: @Nizar this is a direct proof from the definitions, d|x and d|y implies d|x+y. Just write $x=dk$ and $y=dj$.

Comment: @AdamHughes yes , but may be  $d|b$ but $d$ does not divide  $2b$ ?

Comment: so because we can have acombination that produces both a and b that mean the gcd of (a+2b,b) must be divisible by both a and b. and since the gcd(a,b) =1 that means that gcd(a+2b,b) must also equla to 1. Am I correct in my logic?

Comment: @Nizar of course, $dm=b$ for some $m$ so $2b=2dm=d(2m)$. It's immediate from the definition of divides.

Comment: @lodnots3 yes, since the gcd divides 1 it must be equal to 1.

Comment: @AdamHughes yes i get it thanks.

Comment: @Nizar no problem, glad to help clear up the confusion. :)

Comment: @AdamHughes Thanks